# PHP check box to determine mailing destination

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a mailform that I use. In a new usage I have added 2 checkboxes. I would like to be able to send mail to differing addresses based on the check boxes.
EX: if "box1 checked mail to xx, if box 2 checked mail to xx, else mail to both. The code That I use to mail is:

```
<?

/************************
* Variables you can change
*************************/

$mailto = "";
$cc = "";
$bcc = "";
$subject = "contact";
$vname = "Enquiry";


/************************
* do not modify anything below unless you know PHP/HTML/XHTML
*************************/
/* my trial adjustment for check boxes
*/


$email = $_POST['email'];

function validateEmail($email)
{
   if(eregi('^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?$', $email))
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}


if((strlen($_POST['name']) < 1 ) || (strlen($email) < 1 ) || (strlen($_POST['message']) < 1 ) || validateEmail($email) == FALSE){
    $emailerror .= '';

    if(strlen($_POST['name']) < 1 ){
        $emailerror .= '<li>Enter name</li>';
    }

    if(strlen($email) < 1 ){
        $emailerror .= '<li>Enter email</li>';
    }

    if(validateEmail($email) == FALSE) {
        $emailerror .= '<li>Enter valid email</li>';
    }

    if(strlen($_POST['message']) < 1 ){
        $emailerror .= '<li>Enter message</li>';
    }

} else {

    $emailerror .= "Your email has been sent successfully";



    // NOW SEND THE ENQUIRY

    $timestamp = date("F j, Y, g:ia");

    $messageproper ="\n\n" .
        "Name: " .
        ucwords($_POST['name']) .
        "\n" .
        "Email: " .
        ucwords($email) .
        "\n" .
        "Telephone Contact: " .
        ucwords($_POST['tel']) .
        "\n" .
        "Company: " .
        ucwords($_POST['company']) .
        "\n" .
        "Comments: " .
        $_POST['message'] .
        "\n" .
        "\n\n" ;

        $messageproper = trim(stripslashes($messageproper));
        mail($mailto, $subject, $messageproper, "From: \"$vname\" <".$_POST['e_mail'].">\nReply-To: \"".ucwords($_POST['first_name'])."\" <".$_POST['e_mail'].">\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() );

}
?>

<div id='emailerror'>
    <ul>
        <? echo $emailerror; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The check box code:

```
   <label>MailPersonA</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="A" value="checkbox" id="A" />
   <label>MailPersonB</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="B" value="checkbox" id="B" />
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to:

- use radio inputs instead of checkboxes, to make sure exactly one is chosen
- name the radios the same
- give them different values

So your HTML would be

```
<label>MailPersonA</label>
<input type="radio" name="toaddress" value="person1@wherever.com" id="A" />
<label>MailPersonB</label>
<input type="radio" name="toaddress" value="person2@wherever.com" id="B" />
```

Now `$_POST['toaddress']` will contain the destination email address.

Comment: I believe in order for `$_POST['toaddress']` to hold _both_ addresses, you need to use `name="toaddress[]"` in the form. Then both values will exist in `$_POST['toaddress']` as an array.

Comment: True.  I was trying to for the user to choose just one email address.

Comment: Oh, I see your `type="radio"` now. My bad. :)

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably do better with:

```
   <label>MailPersonA</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="emailadd[]" value="email1@example.com" id="A" />
   <label>MailPersonB</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="emailadd[]" value="email2@example.com" id="B" />
```

and then in processing:

```
if($_POST['emailadd']) {
    foreach($_POST['emailadd'] as $email) {
         $mailto.= $email . ',';
    }

$mailto= trim($mailto,',');
```

It'd probably be a good idea to add the emails on the back end based on the values from the form, rather than putting them right in the form like I did here. I was just simplifying for the sake of example.

Comment: I agree that the email addresses should be mapped on the back end. If the email address itself is passed in the `POST` data, then malicious folks could use the form to spam others with your web server.